# How to find documents by values of two fields of sub-document?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 4 records in my db

```
{c: [{d:1, e:0}, {d:2, e:0}]}    
{c: [{d:1, e:1}, {d:2, e:0}]}    
{c: [{d:1, e:0}, {d:2, e:1}]}
{c: [{d:1, e:1}, {d:2, e:1}]}
```

and I want to find only the document where any of the `c` field's array elements has `d` being equal to `1` and `e` being equal to `0` at the same time.
If I execute query such like:

```
db.b.find({"c.d": 1, "c:e": 0})
```

or

```
db.b.find({$and: [{"c.d": 1}, {"c:e": 0}]})
```

database returns 3 results where `c.d` = `1` and `c.e` = `0`, but not for the same sub-document. How can I form the request based on my criteria which will return me only the first and third record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/). It allows you to specify the values matching in **one** array element.

```js
db.b.find({ c: {$elemMatch: { d: 1, e: 0 } } })
```

That gives you the whole document that has the matching element. If you want to only see the matching array element in the response, use projection on the field, as in:

```js
db.b.find({ c: {$elemMatch: { d: 1, e: 0 } } },{ "c.$": 1 })
```

And other *non-matching* array elements will not be shown.

Comment: Thanks, it works great and shows me my error by finding not one but two documents, lol

Comment: @FLCL Why did I know you would say that? It's two array elements and not two documents. But I already added that part to the answer because I just knew you would say this. See how to get what you want with the updated information.